# Angular-translate not working with static json content

Tags: html, json, angularjs, localization

Angular translation works fine if the symabol and translation is provided inside $translateProvider.translations() . However , when I attempt to perform translation with value from a json file, translation is not working .

```
    var mymodel= angular.module('mymodel',['pascalprecht.translate']).
    config(function($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    HEADLINE: 'Hello there, This is my awesome app!',
    INTRO_TEXT: 'And it has i18n support!'
  }) .translations('de', {
    HEADLINE: 'Hey, das ist meine großartige App!',
    INTRO_TEXT: 'Und sie untersützt mehrere Sprachen!'
  });

 $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
  prefix: 'https://localhost/angular%20seed/app/js/languages/',
  suffix: '.json'
});
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('de');
        $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('de');


    // $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
});
```

**My html file is**

```
<html ng-app="mymodel">
<head>
    <title> Sing up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
     <script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-translate.js"></script>    
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Controllers/FirstController.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin-left:200px">
    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
   {{ 'INTRO_TEXT' | translate }}
  {{ 'INTRO_TEXT1' | translate }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**de.json (Path : `https://localhost/angular%20seed/app/js/languages/de.json`)**

```
{
    "HEADLINE1": "Hey, das ist meine großartige App!",
    "INTRO_TEXT1": "Und sie untersützt mehrere Sprachen!"
  }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  Und sie untersÃ¼tzt mehrere Sprachen!
INTRO_TEXT1
```

**EDIT**
I'm not receiving any error message .

Comment: what the HTTP request url and status ? 404 ? does this match an existing file ? tried with a relative path instead of absolute ?

Comment: Does your server respond with JSON?